# Cannot get wildcard certificate with traefik v2 and godaddy

Tags: lets-encrypt, traefik, wildcard-subdomain, godaddy-api

I'm trying to set up a wildcard certificate mechanism with traefik v2.2 and GoDaddy. What I want to do is generating a valid certificate for the URLs pattern *.example.org. Here there is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.2
    container_name: traefik
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .provider.env
      # .provider.env contains `GODADDY_API_KEY` and `GODADDY_API_SECRET`
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./tls-certificates:/tls-certificates
    ports:
      # http
      - 8080:80
      # https
      - 443:443
    command:
      - --api.dashboard=true
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --providers.docker.network=proxy
      - --entrypoints.webinsecure.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443

      # --certificatesresolvers.<name> Certificates resolvers configuration
      # ACME V2 supports wildcard certificates.
      # Wildcard certificates can only be generated through a DNS-01 challenge.
      - --certificatesresolvers.wildcard-godaddy.acme.tlschallenge=true
      - --certificatesResolvers.wildcard-godaddy.acme.dnsChallenge.provider=godaddy
      - --certificatesResolvers.wildcard-godaddy.acme.dnsChallenge.delayBeforeCheck=0
      # Email address used for registration.
      - --certificatesresolvers.wildcard-godaddy.acme.email=foo@example.org
      # Certificates storage
      - --certificatesresolvers.wildcard-godaddy.acme.storage=/tls-certificates/acme.json

    networks:
      - proxy

    labels:

      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=webinsecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik.example.org`)"

      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=${DASHBOARD_USERNAME}:${DASHBOARD_PASSWORD}"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-https-redirect"

      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.rule=Host(`traefik.example.org`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.middlewares=traefik-auth"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.certresolver=wildcard-godaddy"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[0].main=example.org"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[0].sans=*.example.org"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.service=api@internal"


networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

In my dns I have an `A` record `*` pointing to my ip address.

However when I start the compose I get the following error:

```
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:40:50Z" level=debug msg="No default certificate, generating one"
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:40:51Z" level=debug msg="Looking for provided certificate(s) to validate [\"example.org\" \"*.example.org\"]..." providerName=wildcard-godaddy.acme
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:40:51Z" level=debug msg="Domains [\"example.org\" \"*.example.org\"] need ACME certificates generation for domains \"example.org,*.example.org\"." providerName=wildcard-godaddy.acme
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:40:51Z" level=debug msg="Loading ACME certificates [example.org *.example.org]..." providerName=wildcard-godaddy.acme
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:40:51Z" level=debug msg="Building ACME client..." providerName=wildcard-godaddy.acme
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:40:51Z" level=debug msg="https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory" providerName=wildcard-godaddy.acme
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:40:51Z" level=debug msg="Using DNS Challenge provider: godaddy" providerName=wildcard-godaddy.acme
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:40:51Z" level=debug msg="Using TLS Challenge provider." providerName=wildcard-godaddy.acme
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:40:51Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [example.org, *.example.org] acme: Obtaining bundled SAN certificate"
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:40:52Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [*.example.org] AuthURL: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/id1"
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:40:52Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [example.org] AuthURL: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/id2"
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:40:52Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [*.example.org] acme: use dns-01 solver"
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:40:52Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [example.org] acme: use tls-alpn-01 solver"
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:40:52Z" level=debug msg="TLS Challenge Present temp certificate for example.org" providerName=acme
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:40:52Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [example.org] acme: Trying to solve TLS-ALPN-01"
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:40:58Z" level=debug msg="TLS Challenge CleanUp temp certificate for example.org" providerName=acme
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:40:58Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [*.example.org] acme: Preparing to solve DNS-01"
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:40:58Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [*.example.org] acme: Trying to solve DNS-01"
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:40:58Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [*.example.org] acme: Checking DNS record propagation using [127.0.0.11:53]"
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:40:58Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] Wait for propagation [timeout: 2m0s, interval: 2s]"
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:40:58Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [*.example.org] acme: Waiting for DNS record propagation."
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:41:00Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [*.example.org] acme: Waiting for DNS record propagation."
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:41:02Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [*.example.org] acme: Waiting for DNS record propagation."
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:41:04Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [*.example.org] acme: Waiting for DNS record propagation."
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:41:06Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [*.example.org] acme: Waiting for DNS record propagation."
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:41:08Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [*.example.org] acme: Waiting for DNS record propagation."
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:41:10Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [*.example.org] acme: Waiting for DNS record propagation."
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:41:12Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [*.example.org] acme: Waiting for DNS record propagation."
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:41:14Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [*.example.org] acme: Waiting for DNS record propagation."
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:41:21Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [*.example.org] acme: Cleaning DNS-01 challenge"
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:41:22Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] Deactivating auth: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/id1"
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:41:22Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] Unable to deactivate the authorization: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/id1"
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:41:22Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] Deactivating auth: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/id2"
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:41:22Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] Unable to deactivate the authorization: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/id2"
traefik    | time="2020-04-15T16:41:22Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"example.org,*.example.org\" : unable to generate a certificate for the domains [example.org *.example.org]: acme: Error -> One or more domains had a problem:\n[*.example.org] acme: error: 403 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: During secondary validation: Incorrect TXT record \"null\" found at _acme-challenge.example.org, url: \n[example.org] acme: error: 400 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:connection :: Connection refused, url: \n" providerName=wildcard-godaddy.acme
```

I do not understand either I'm misconfiguring something or if there's a problem on the let's encrypt/godaddy side.

**Edit:**

On port 80 I have another nginx instance up & running

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turned out it was a bug (fixed in `v.2.2.1`). See here: https://github.com/go-acme/lego/issues/1113